# Get Following people on twitter with OAuth method? Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, twitter, oauth

I create an object:

```
 SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *_engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
```

then set the consumerKey and the consumerSecret...
I can get the followers without problems by calling:

```
[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:0];
```

Everything fine until now: I have to get the people that the user follows and I could't find an appropiate method for it.

Does somebody out there a method to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Sounds like something you should check out the Twitter API for.

Comment: i can't find it in the api!!! That's why i posted it here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this page of source code](http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/source/browse/branches/v2_0_dev/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterEngine.h?r=102#122) it looks like the method you want might be `getRecentlyUpdatedFriendsFor`.